# Fabric : /ios/Pods/Fabric/run”: No such file or directory

Tags: ios, objective-c, react-native, crashlytics, google-fabric

using pod to install fabric but getting `/ios/Pods/Fabric/run”: No such file or directory`,
i added run script in

```
 “${PODS_ROOT}/Fabric/run”  <API KEY> <S KEY>”
```

show environment variable in build log is checked ,

whats issue not able to get ,

here is pod version

```
pod 'Fabric', '~> 1.7.6'
pod 'Crashlytics', '~> 3.10.1'
```

Comment: Hi, Paul from Fabric here, is it possible that your PODS_ROOT command is surrounded with Smart Quotes? Or is that just the copying and pasting to StackOverflow? The Smart Quotes would make the command fail like this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please check if you are using correct quotation marks.
You can copy code from below and just replece abc123 with correct values.

```
"${PODS_ROOT}/Fabric/run" abc123 abc123
```

I assume you have run the command `pod install`, don't you?

Answer (score 8):

Using Flutter this came up again after the most recent update of Crashlytics.

Adding `pod 'Fabric'` to the Podfile fixed this.

Comment: how do you add the pod to the podfile

Answer (score 8):

I stumbled upon this issue after upgrading to the new Crashlytics SDK as of recent. The issue for the main post and my issue is probably different but I thought I'd just put it here anyways in case someone else stumbled upon it.

After updating my pods to use the newest SDK which will replace the old one starting November 15th 2020, I kept getting this error and I realised that its because the path to Fabric/run was still set in the Build Phases run script.

So beware that the info on the google page is not enough to upgrade your sdk
https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/upgrade-sdk?platform=ios

You should actually perform all the steps that are explained in the getting started guide instead.
https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/get-started?platform=ios

Step 3 is about changing the build phases within Xcode to properly use the new sdk version.

Comment: correct, i also deleted previously added Fabric's run script after adding new crashlytics' run script

Comment: Yep, this could be a troublesome issue if you forget the build scripts lol

Answer (score 6):

The other answers are outdated (I don't have ability to edit or comment).

Use `${PODS_ROOT}/FirebaseCrashlytics/run` in your build scripts instead

1. From Xcode select Runner from the project navigation.
2. Find existing Crashlytics script
3. Modify script to point to `FirebaseCrashlytics` instead of `Crashlytics`

---

Change is needed since Firebase team renamed the plugin

Answer (score 2):

I've had the same issue in 2022.
Xcode 14.0.1
Node: 16.10.0
React-native: 0.70.3
I was trying to upgrade my project from react 0.60.2
And the issue was that Fabric was replaced with FirebaseCrashlytics.
The solution is:
Replace the `"${PODS_ROOT}/Fabric/run"` in Build Phases > Run Script
with `"${PODS_ROOT}/FirebaseCrashlytics/run"`
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I am using crashlytics through react-native-firebase

Even after making sure everything was typed in correctly I was still getting this error. Turns out my issue was that the Crashlytics Configuration was not under the Build Phases tab for my project. I re-ran pod install and it generated a [CP-USER][RNFB] Crashlytics Configuration under Build Phases tab and everything worked after that

Comment: getting the same issue