# The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, in Flutter How can I change the minimum IOS Deploying Target

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter

I changed everything to 9.0 in the project but I'm having the same error in a lot of pods.

I tried doing a lot of different things but nothing worked. Does anyone know how can I fix this?

```
warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is
9.0 to 14.0.99. (in target 'gRPC-C++-gRPCCertificates-Cpp' from project 'Pods')
warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is
9.0 to 14.0.99. (in target 'GoogleAppMeasurement' from project 'Pods')
warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is
9.0 to 14.0.99. (in target 'FirebaseAuth' from project 'Pods')
warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is
9.0 to 14.0.99. (in target 'GoogleUtilities' from project 'Pods')
warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is
9.0 to 14.0.99. (in target 'vibration' from project 'Pods')
warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is
9.0 to 14.0.99. (in target 'nanopb' from project 'Pods')
warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is
9.0 to 14.0.99. (in target 'BoringSSL-GRPC' from project 'Pods')
warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is
9.0 to 14.0.99. (in target 'gRPC-Core' from project 'Pods')
warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is
9.0 to 14.0.99. (in target 'gRPC-C++' from project 'Pods')
```

Encountered error while building for device.

Comment: Please note, however, that these are just warnings! They are not errors. Therefore, if your build crashes, it's because of something else, not the above. Run a search for the word "error" in your build output! :)

Answer (score 93, accepted):

I solve it with this code, thanks!
At the end of the PodFile

```
post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    target.build_configurations.each do |config|
      config.build_settings.delete 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET'
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Seems interesting, can you explain it's functioning? thanks

Comment: Does not work for me, getting error while building
** BUILD FAILED **
Xcode's output:
↳
    In file included from
    flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/path_provider-1.6.27/ios/Classes/FLTPathProviderPlugin.m:5:flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/path_provider-1.6.27/ios/Classes/FLTPathProviderPlugin.h:5:9:fatal error: 'Flutter/Flutter.h'
    file not found
    #import <Flutter/Flutter.h>
            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    1 error generated.
note: Using new build system
note: Building targets in parallel
note: Planning build
note: Constructing build description

Comment: @HarshPhoujdar I'm facing the same issue, did you solve it?

Comment: @DavideBicego I have been stuck for past week on this, I am hoping someone replies and helps us. I have gone through a myriad of stackoverflow answers and tried everything. Basically it seems to be stuck in a loop where one solution says to downgrade cocoapods, and flutter 2 says to keep the latest ones.

Comment: @HarshPhoujdar I managed to solve the issue updating most of my dependences. In particular Firebase packages were the problematic ones. They were not compatible with flutter v2 probably. I went from firebase_core: ^0.7.0, firebase_crashlytics: ^0.4.0+1, firebase_messaging: ^8.0.0-dev.15 to firebase_core: ^1.0.4, firebase_crashlytics: ^2.0.1, firebase_messaging: ^9.1.2

Comment: @bks It deletes the deployment target included for all the targets, so it's set to the default determined by Xcode.

Comment: @ReinstateMonica3167040 Thank you!

Comment: when i did so. and try to fun. it showed flutter.h not found ...

Comment: @Sras For flutter apps, `flutter_additional_ios_build_settings(target)` should be added after line `installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|`.

Comment: @goldensoju i dont know somehow, it works when i try to reinstall the gem.

Answer (score 233):

What worked for me is a combination of @raffaelli-l-c and @arhan-reddy-busam answer.

Ensure that you do the following:

- Set `MinimumOSVersion` to 9.0 in `ios/Flutter/AppFrameworkInfo.plist`
- Ensure that you uncomment `platform :ios, '9.0'` in `ios/Podfile`
- Ensure that `ios/Podfile` contains the following post install script:

```
    post_install do |installer|
      installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
        flutter_additional_ios_build_settings(target)
        target.build_configurations.each do |config|
          config.build_settings['IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET'] = '9.0'
        end
      end
    end
```

The following routine works for me when doing my production build:

```
    flutter clean \
        && rm ios/Podfile.lock pubspec.lock \
        && rm -rf ios/Pods ios/Runner.xcworkspace \
        && flutter build ios --build-name=1.0.0 --build-number=1 --release --dart-define=MY_APP_ENV=prod
```

Comment: `flutter clean && rm ios/Podfile.lock pubspec.lock && rm -rf ios/Pods ios/Runner.xcworkspace` just executing this did the trick for me

Comment: I think this is really ridiculous that we have to edit the Podfile manually for almost a year now. But yes, this does solve the problem.

Comment: Does not work for me, getting
Generate
    dPluginRegistrant.h:8:9: error:
    'Flutter/Flutter.h' file not found
    #import <Flutter/Flutter.h>        ^
    1 error generated.
    <unknown>:0: error: failed to emit
    precompiled header

Comment: This is finally what worked for me. I was getting an error that said 
`Error: Member not found: 'packageRoot'. ../…/interface/local_platform.dart:46`
`io.Platform.packageRoot; // ignore: deprecated_member_use`

Comment: Even if I put the `MinimumOSVersion` to "99.0" in `ios/Flutter/AppFrameworkInfo.plist`, it does nothing! My minimum target iOS is still too low!... Seems Flutter ignores this setting. 

Comment: Looks like we are in 15 century. Anything that has to do with cocoapods and xcode.. is just throwing totally random delete commands... without no result. what a joke.

Answer (score 23):

go to Pods and for each framework you're using change the iOS version as shown in my screenshot

[image]

Comment: This is not correct (at least, not completely) - the script in ios/Podfile is supposed to do this operation automatically, check @"Je suis alrick" answer please!

Answer (score 17):

This is because XCode 12 does only support building for the iOS target versions 9 - 14. Unfortunately the default iOS target set by flutter is 8. But you should be able to change the target in the ios/Runner.xcworkspace file using XCode. See [flutter documentation](https://flutter.dev/docs/deployment/ios) section "Review Xcode project settings" -> headline "Deployment Target:".

You could also try updating flutter to 1.22 beta, which supports iOS 14 and XCode 12 (as noted [here](https://medium.com/flutter/supporting-ios-14-and-xcode-12-with-flutter-15fe0062e98b))

Comment: I think Apple needs to work for developer it is so tricky

Comment: I think Flutter should do a better job of updating the builds. ^

Comment: @rounpaleum if you ever write native code you know that apple does it. I actually forced to do react-native right now and it's a hell compared to go all in native on both plattforms. Every upgrade is a pain in the a**

Answer (score 7):

I tried a bunch of things but what seems to have fixed this for me was:

```
flutter pub cache repair
```

https://dart.dev/tools/pub/cmd/pub-cache

Comment: I had to run the command this way: `flutter pub cache repair`

Comment: Thank you for the updated solution. 
this was the only one worked for me. :)

Answer (score 5):

You need to update your pod file

**iOS Project**:

1. Set platform OS & version, first line of Pod file, for me its...

`platform :ios, '13.6'`

2. Add this additional code to your pod file:

> ```
> post_install do |installer|
>   installer.generated_projects.each do |project|
>     project.targets.each do |target|
>       target.build_configurations.each do |config|
>         config.build_settings['IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET'] = '13.6'
>       end
>     end
>   end
> end
> ```

**macOS Project**:

1. Set platform OS & version, first line of Pod file, for me its...

`platform :macos, '11.5'`

2. Add this additional code to your pod file:

> ```
> post_install do |installer|
>   installer.generated_projects.each do |project|
>     project.targets.each do |target|
>       target.build_configurations.each do |config|
>         config.build_settings['MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET'] = '11.5'
>       end
>     end
>   end
> end
> ```

Similar for tvOS & watchOS

tvOS - `['TVOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET'] = 'VERSION'`

watchOS - `['WATCHOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET'] = 'VERSION'`

That’s it, Cheers!

Answer (score 4):

All these answers, and in fact, you can safely ignore those logs!  They're just warnings, not errors!

If your build fails, it's because of something else, not this. Do a `Command + F` in the output logs of your build and search for the word "error". That will tell you what the real problem is.

(Then again, if you REALLY want to get rid of those warnings, you can do a `Command + Shift + F` in your Android Studio project, or just a global search of some sort if you're using a different IDE, and search for 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET'. Then, everywhere you see that value set to '8.0' inside your pods, you can change it to '9.0' or '10.0' or whatever value you want that's within the specified range. This won't do anything to the function of your app, but you won't have to see the warnings again!)

Answer (score 3):

After couple of days trying to figure out what to do.

The only thing that worked for me was deleting the entire ios directory in my Flutter project, then rebuilding it:

```
flutter create .
```

Add `GoogleService-Info.plist` to Runner.
Add signing & capabilities in Xcode.
Add target properties in Xcode such as sign-in.

As mentioned in:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/67224108/7749979

Comment: By doing this it actually created the necessary flutter content in the Podfile.

Answer (score 2):

For me what worked is, open XCode in ios folder. Then check and fix possible account related problem in Signing section. Then run `flutter run` again. And it worked. Not sure why is it related to this error but it worked.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure, in any of your dart files has not imported the dart.html package.
This caused a problem in my case when flutter tries to install the pod.

Comment: thank god, you saved me so much time. Sometimes it's imported accidentally

Answer (score 1):

I got so fed up, so I just compiled in Xcode 13.  Works for me!
Since upgrading to Flutter 2.5.2, I got this weird issue. Minor hassle.

ios/Podfile:

```
platform :ios, '10.0'
```

[I change minimumOS to 10](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jUmj9.png)

Answer (score 1):

Change MinimumOSVersion to 9.0 in /ios/Flutter/AppFrameworkInfo.plist.

Then in ios/Runner.xcodeproj/project.bpxproj replace
`IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET = 8.0` to `IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET = 9.0` in three lines.

It also works if you are building your .ipa whit codemagic

Answer (score 0):

Just Follow Below Command Line in Your macOS

1. flutter clean
2. rm ios/Podfile.lock pubspec.lock
3. rm ios/Podfile.lock pubspec.lock
4. rm -rf ios/Pods ios/Runner.xcworkspace

Answer (score 0):

[image]

1. Open Xcode
2. Change Project Document - Project format - Xcode 8.0-Compatible
3. Flutter clean, flutter pub get and flutter build iOS

Answer (score 0):

After trying most of these solutions the only thing that worked for me is to uncomment and add ios 10 in *ios/Podfile*:

```
platform :ios, '10.0'
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case this error was misleading.

Turns out, the problem was caused by a missing step in Firebase upgrade docs: delete the Fabric build step in XCode.

Here's the article I found that actually solved the cause of this error for me: [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50589904/fabric-ios-pods-fabric-run-no-such-file-or-directory) towards the bottom it mentions the Fabric dependency.

I added the new Run Script in XCode per the firebase docs referenced, removed the Fabric related build phase, and the 8.0 target error went away.

I hope this helps anyone else who went down the PodFile dependency rabbit hole that I did.

Answer (score 0):

I recently upgraded nodejs with nvm and got this error (using React Native btw). I tried everything that does not require code changes. After switching back from nodejs 16 to 14, it worked again. But it wasn't the root cause. Try to read everything above the error. For me there was a line:

```
nvm is not compatible with the "npm_config_prefix" environment variable
```

After upgrading nvm from 0.33 to 0.39 it worked, even with nodejs 16

Answer (score -2):

When updating to iOs 14.4 it seems that the path_provider package is not compatible with target 10.0. Currently Firebase package requires target 10.0. Here's the problem, I've had the problem for a month now. Maybe the Flutter team can help. When building iOs, there is an error that cannot be fixed, hic hic.

Launching lib/main.dart on iPhone 12 Pro in debug mode...
Running pod install...
Running Xcode build...
Xcode build done.                                           29.4s
Failed to build iOS app
Error output from Xcode build:
↳
** BUILD FAILED **

Xcode's output:
↳
In file included from /Users/maitrongtue/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/path_provider-2.0.1/ios/Classes/FLTPathProviderPlugin.m:5:
/Users/maitrongtue/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/path_provider-2.0.1/ios/Classes/FLTPathProviderPlugin.h:5:9: fatal error: 'Flutter/Flutter.h' file not found
#import <Flutter/Flutter.h>
^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
note: Using new build system
note: Building targets in parallel
note: Planning build
note: Constructing build description

Could not build the application for the simulator.
Error launching application on iPhone 12 Pro.