# Flutter: 'UIAlertView' is deprecated: first deprecated in iOS 9.0

Tags: ios, flutter

I got the following error:

```
/Users/flo/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/image_picker-0.6.7+12/ios/Classes/FLTImagePickerPlugin.m:1
    49:20: warning: 'UIAlertView' is deprecated: first deprecated in iOS 9.0 - UIAlertView is deprecated.
    Use UIAlertController with a preferredStyle of UIAlertControllerStyleAlert instead
    [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
        [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error"
```

I already try to do:

`flutter pub cache repair`

rm the .pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org directory

rm podfile.lock and Pods folder

But still the same issue. Any ideas ? I only find issues like this for Swift but not related to Flutter.

Comment: Did you try to use a `UIAlertView` in your project? (I know exactly nothing about Flutter, but `UIAlertView` has, in fact, been deprecated since iOS 9.)

Comment: Yeah I know, but the error is from the package and I'm not suppose to edit it or change IOS code.

Comment: @lab wich package you used i have the same error and im confused, thanks

Comment: image_picker in that case, try to comment the package on the pubspec to see if the error still appear for other packages

Comment: The text you cite is not actually an error, but a warning.  There was probably an error further down in the output.  I came here because I was looking for a solution for the deprecated UIAlertView warning...still looking.

Answer (score 6):

I allow myself to answer my question which may benefit others who have the same problem, here is a simple solution that worked for me. You don't have to repair/update the cache or edit the Podfile and remove the Pods folder.

- Just comment out the package on the Pubspec that generates the error (in that case: image_picker)
- `flutter run` (you may have errors due to the missing package, ignore them)
- Uncomment the line
- Run again and the error should be gone