# Flutter ios : camera/CameraPlugin.h' file not found

Tags: ios, macos, flutter, android-studio

Created Flutter application built on both an Android and iOS device. Application is working fine with android and when i build my ios build it ends up with error as shown below.
Error while executing ios build in android studio using mac device.
i try plenty of method to solve this.

```
**FOLLOWED SETS:**
```

- Flutter clean
  Flutter pub get
  Pod install
  Build.

**Output**

```
    Launching lib/main.dart on iPad in debug mode...
    Automatically signing iOS for device deployment using specified development team in Xcode project: 3MDPB894U7
    Running pod install...
    Running Xcode build...
    Xcode build done.                                           52.7s
    Failed to build iOS app
    Error output from Xcode build:
    ↳
        ** BUILD FAILED **


    Xcode's output:
    ↳
        /Users/apple/AndroidStudioProjects/console/ios/Runner/GeneratedPluginRegistrant.m:12:9: fatal error: module 'camera' not found
        @import camera;
        ~~~~~~~^~~~~~
        1 error generated.
        note: Using new build system
        note: Building targets in parallel
        note: Planning build
        note: Constructing build description

    Could not build the precompiled application for the device.

    Error launching application on iPad.
```

Comment: Try this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64362285/flutter-on-ios-fatal-error-module-cloud-firestore-not-found

Comment: @ Lab Still a ends up with the same error message

Answer (score 4):

Change the target version to above 10.0.
Change in the Project Runner (in Xcode), PodFile & Target Runner (in Xcode), then run Pod Install

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you open the `.xcworkspace` file instead of the `.xcodeproj`. This helped me to solve the issue.