# Getting error when running app on iOS simulator in Flutter after installing cloud_firestore package

Tags: ios, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, flutter-dependencies, absl-py

I have tried even `pod update Firebase/Firestore` still getting below error when running on iOS simulator after installing `cloud_firestore` package.

Even I have tried to delete Podfile.lock many times and `flutter clean` then `flutter run`.

**Note**:

1. **Flutter version: Flutter 2.0.2**
2. **Dart 2.12.1**

   Failed to build iOS app
   Error output from Xcode build:
   ↳
   ** BUILD FAILED **

   ```
   Xcode's output:
   ↳
       In file included from /Users/gwl/firebase_demo/ios/Pods/abseil/absl/base/internal/thread_identity.cc:26:
       In file included from /Users/gwl/firebase_demo/ios/Pods/abseil/absl/base/call_once.h:34:
       /Users/gwl/firebase_demo/ios/Pods/abseil/absl/base/internal/invoke.h:42:10: fatal error: 'absl/meta/type_traits.h' file not found
       #include "absl/meta/type_traits.h"
                ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
       /Users/gwl/firebase_demo/ios/Pods/abseil/absl/base/internal/invoke.h:42:10: note: did not find header 'meta/type_traits.h' in framework 'absl' (loaded from
       '/Users/gwl/firebase_demo/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/abseil')
       1 error generated.
       note: Using new build system
       note: Building targets in parallel
       note: Planning build
       note: Constructing build description

   Could not build the application for the simulator.
   Error launching application on iPhone 11.
   ```

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64362285/flutter-on-ios-fatal-error-module-cloud-firestore-not-found)

Answer (score 2):

U need to delete the podfile.lock

then u need to run iOS folder from XCode to load assets for your projects

Go to ios folder and execute `pod install` and if it doesn't exist execute `pod init` then `pod install`

Please try Xcode -> Product -> Run

Answer (score 2):

First delete podfile.lock and follow the steps below ;

```
flutter clean
flutter pub get
cd ios
pod install
flutter run
```

If doesnt work check your flutter channel and change it to beta.

```
flutter pub upgrade
flutter channel beta
flutter clean
cd ios
pod install
flutter run
```

Also you can switch back to stable typing below;

```
flutter channel beta
```

Answer (score 1):

This solved my issue [GitHub issue](https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/issues/6448)

try running these commands in your ios directory:

```
rm -rf Pods
rm -rf Podfile.lock
rm -rf ~/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/
pod cache clean --all
flutter clean
flutter pub get
pod repo update
pod install
```