# flutter xcode build error Module 'cloud_firestore' not found

Tags: xcode, flutter

xcode build error : Module 'cloud_firestore' not found
I've tried all the methods in the link below,
but it still doesn't work.

[Flutter on IOS: fatal error: module 'cloud_firestore' not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64362285/flutter-on-ios-fatal-error-module-cloud-firestore-not-found)

If anyone has had the same experience recently,
please help.

Comment: have you inserted the cloud firestore dependency?

Comment: yes. cloud_firestore: ^2.5.3

Comment: How did you solve it?