# Flutter iOS: module cloud_firestore not found

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter, macos, google-cloud-firestore

When I try to build the app with XCode on emulator or iPhone I get this error in GeneratedPluginRegistrant file:

`module cloud_firestore not found`

#### What I've tried

1. rebuilt iOS folder
2. added **$FirebaseSDKVersion = '8.10.0'** in Podfile (with or without it I have the same problem)
3. added **config.build_settings['IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET'] = '12.0'** in Podfile (with or without it I have the same problem)
4. pod deintegrate, pod update, flutter clean, flutter pub get, flutter build ios, removed pod files...
5. set MinimumOSVersion to 12.0
6. Updated flutter, packages, macOS, Xcode

can anyone help me?

#### Podfile

Click To Expand

```
# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, '12.0'

# CocoaPods analytics sends network stats synchronously affecting flutter build latency.
ENV['COCOAPODS_DISABLE_STATS'] = 'true'

$FirebaseSDKVersion = '8.10.0'

project 'Runner', {
  'Debug' => :debug,
  'Profile' => :release,
  'Release' => :release,
}

def flutter_root
  generated_xcode_build_settings_path = File.expand_path(File.join('..', 'Flutter', 'Generated.xcconfig'), __FILE__)
  unless File.exist?(generated_xcode_build_settings_path)
    raise "#{generated_xcode_build_settings_path} must exist. If you're running pod install manually, make sure flutter pub get is executed first"
  end

  File.foreach(generated_xcode_build_settings_path) do |line|
    matches = line.match(/FLUTTER_ROOT\=(.*)/)
    return matches[1].strip if matches
  end
  raise "FLUTTER_ROOT not found in #{generated_xcode_build_settings_path}. Try deleting Generated.xcconfig, then run flutter pub get"
end

require File.expand_path(File.join('packages', 'flutter_tools', 'bin', 'podhelper'), flutter_root)

flutter_ios_podfile_setup

target 'Runner' do
  use_frameworks!
  use_modular_headers!

  flutter_install_all_ios_pods File.dirname(File.realpath(__FILE__))
end

post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    flutter_additional_ios_build_settings(target)
    target.build_configurations.each do |config|
     config.build_settings['IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET'] = '12.0'
    end
  end
end
```

---

#### Flutter doctor

Run `flutter doctor` and paste the output below:

Click To Expand

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.8.1, on macOS 12.1 21C52 darwin-x64, locale
    it-IT)
[✗] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices
    ✗ Unable to locate Android SDK.
      Install Android Studio from:
      https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html
      On first launch it will assist you in installing the Android SDK
      components.
      (or visit https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/macos#android-setup
      for detailed instructions).
      If the Android SDK has been installed to a custom location, please use
      flutter config --android-sdk to update to that location.

[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 13.2.1)
[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
[!] Android Studio (not installed)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.63.2)
[✓] Connected device (1 available)

! Doctor found issues in 2 categories.
```

---

#### Flutter dependencies

Click To Expand

```
dependencies:
- auto_size_text 3.0.0 [flutter]
- cloud_firestore 3.1.6 [cloud_firestore_platform_interface cloud_firestore_web collection firebase_core firebase_core_platform_interface flutter meta]
- cloud_functions 3.2.5 [cloud_functions_platform_interface cloud_functions_web firebase_core firebase_core_platform_interface flutter]
- collection 1.15.0
- cupertino_icons 1.0.4
- dio 4.0.4 [http_parser path]
- ext_storage 1.0.3 [flutter]
- file_picker 4.3.0 [flutter flutter_web_plugins flutter_plugin_android_lifecycle plugin_platform_interface ffi path]
- firebase_analytics 9.0.5 [firebase_analytics_platform_interface firebase_analytics_web firebase_core firebase_core_platform_interface flutter]
- firebase_auth 3.3.5 [firebase_auth_platform_interface firebase_auth_web firebase_core firebase_core_platform_interface flutter meta]
- firebase_core 1.11.0 [firebase_core_platform_interface firebase_core_web flutter meta]
- firebase_crashlytics 2.4.5 [firebase_core firebase_core_platform_interface firebase_crashlytics_platform_interface flutter stack_trace]
- firebase_messaging 11.2.5 [firebase_core firebase_core_platform_interface firebase_messaging_platform_interface firebase_messaging_web flutter meta]
- firebase_storage 10.2.5 [firebase_core firebase_core_platform_interface firebase_storage_platform_interface firebase_storage_web flutter]
- flutter 0.0.0 [characters collection meta typed_data vector_math sky_engine]
- flutter_background_service 0.1.7 [flutter]
- flutter_bloc 8.0.1 [flutter bloc provider]
- flutter_localizations 0.0.0 [flutter intl characters clock collection meta path typed_data vector_math]
- font_awesome_flutter 9.2.0 [flutter]
- get 4.6.1 [flutter]
- get_it 7.2.0 [async collection]
- google_fonts 2.2.0 [flutter http path_provider crypto]
- image_picker 0.8.4+4 [flutter flutter_plugin_android_lifecycle image_picker_for_web image_picker_platform_interface]
- image_picker_for_web 2.1.4 [flutter flutter_web_plugins image_picker_platform_interface meta]
- intl 0.17.0 [clock path]
- json_annotation 4.4.0 [meta]
- native_pdf_renderer 4.0.1 [flutter flutter_web_plugins device_info_plus uuid image js meta extension synchronized universal_platform]
- path_provider 2.0.8 [flutter path_provider_android path_provider_ios path_provider_linux path_provider_macos path_provider_platform_interface path_provider_windows]
- pdf 3.6.5 [archive barcode crypto image meta path_parsing vector_math xml]
- pedometer 3.0.0 [flutter]
- permission_handler 8.3.0 [flutter meta permission_handler_platform_interface]
- shared_preferences 2.0.11 [flutter meta shared_preferences_android shared_preferences_ios shared_preferences_linux shared_preferences_macos shared_preferences_platform_interface shared_preferences_web shared_preferences_windows]
- url_launcher 6.0.17 [flutter meta url_launcher_android url_launcher_ios url_launcher_linux url_launcher_macos url_launcher_platform_interface url_launcher_web url_launcher_windows]
- uuid 3.0.5 [crypto]

dev dependencies:
- build_runner 2.1.7 [args async analyzer build build_config build_daemon build_resolvers build_runner_core code_builder collection crypto dart_style frontend_server_client glob graphs http_multi_server io js logging meta mime package_config path pool pub_semver pubspec_parse shelf shelf_web_socket stack_trace stream_transform timing watcher web_socket_channel yaml]
- change_app_package_name 1.0.0
- flutter_launcher_icons 0.9.2 [args image path yaml]
- flutter_test 0.0.0 [flutter test_api path fake_async clock stack_trace vector_math async boolean_selector characters charcode collection matcher meta source_span stream_channel string_scanner term_glyph typed_data]
- json_serializable 6.1.3 [analyzer async build build_config collection json_annotation meta path pub_semver pubspec_parse source_gen source_helper]

transitive dependencies:
- _fe_analyzer_shared 32.0.0 [meta]
- analyzer 3.0.0 [_fe_analyzer_shared cli_util collection convert crypto glob meta package_config path pub_semver source_span watcher yaml]
- archive 3.1.8 [crypto path]
- args 2.3.0
- async 2.8.2 [collectionmeta]
- barcode 2.2.0 [meta qr]
- bloc 8.0.2 [meta]
- boolean_selector 2.1.0 [source_span string_scanner]
- build 2.2.1 [analyzer async convert crypto glob logging meta path]
- build_config 1.0.0 [checked_yaml json_annotation path pubspec_parse yaml]
- build_daemon 3.0.1 [built_collection built_value http_multi_server logging path pool shelf shelf_web_socket stream_transform watcher web_socket_channel]
- build_resolvers 2.0.6 [analyzer async build crypto graphs logging path package_config pool pub_semver stream_transform yaml]
- build_runner_core 7.2.3 [async build build_config build_resolvers collection convert crypto glob graphs json_annotation logging meta path package_config pool timing watcher yaml]
- built_collection 5.1.1
- built_value 8.1.3 [built_collection collection fixnum meta]
- characters 1.2.0
- charcode 1.3.1
- checked_yaml 2.0.1 [json_annotation source_span yaml]
- cli_util 0.3.5 [meta path]
- clock 1.1.0
- cloud_firestore_platform_interface 5.4.11 [collection firebase_core flutter meta plugin_platform_interface]
- cloud_firestore_web 2.6.6 [cloud_firestore_platform_interface collection firebase_core firebase_core_web flutter flutter_web_plugins js]
- cloud_functions_platform_interface 5.0.20 [firebase_core flutter meta plugin_platform_interface]
- cloud_functions_web 4.2.6 [cloud_functions_platform_interface firebase_core firebase_core_web flutter flutter_web_plugins js]
- code_builder 4.1.0 [built_collection built_value collection matcher meta]
- convert 3.0.1 [typed_data]
- cross_file 0.3.2 [flutter js meta]
- crypto 3.0.1 [collection typed_data]
- dart_style 2.2.1 [analyzer args path pub_semver source_span]
- device_info_plus 3.2.1 [flutter device_info_plus_platform_interface device_info_plus_macos device_info_plus_linux device_info_plus_web device_info_plus_windows]
- device_info_plus_linux 2.1.1 [device_info_plus_platform_interface file flutter meta]
- device_info_plus_macos 2.2.1 [device_info_plus_platform_interface flutter]
- device_info_plus_platform_interface 2.3.0 [flutter meta plugin_platform_interface]
- device_info_plus_web 2.1.0 [device_info_plus_platform_interface flutter_web_plugins flutter]
- device_info_plus_windows 2.1.1 [device_info_plus_platform_interface ffi flutter win32]
- extension 0.2.0
- fake_async 1.2.0 [clock collection]
- ffi 1.1.2
- file 6.1.2 [meta path]
- firebase_analytics_platform_interface 3.0.4 [firebase_core flutter meta plugin_platform_interface]
- firebase_analytics_web 0.4.0+5 [firebase_analytics_platform_interface firebase_core firebase_core_web flutter flutter_web_plugins js]
- firebase_auth_platform_interface 6.1.10 [firebase_core flutter meta plugin_platform_interface]
- firebase_auth_web 3.3.6 [firebase_auth_platform_interface firebase_core firebase_core_web flutter flutter_web_plugins http_parser intl js meta]
- firebase_core_platform_interface 4.2.3 [collection flutter meta plugin_platform_interface]
- firebase_core_web 1.5.3 [firebase_core_platform_interface flutter flutter_web_plugins js meta]
- firebase_crashlytics_platform_interface 3.1.12 [collection firebase_core flutter meta plugin_platform_interface]
- firebase_messaging_platform_interface 3.1.5 [firebase_core flutter meta plugin_platform_interface]
- firebase_messaging_web 2.2.6 [firebase_core firebase_core_web firebase_messaging_platform_interface flutter flutter_web_plugins js meta]
- firebase_storage_platform_interface 4.0.12 [collection firebase_core flutter meta plugin_platform_interface]
- firebase_storage_web 3.2.6 [async firebase_core firebase_core_web firebase_storage_platform_interface flutter flutter_web_plugins http js meta]
- fixnum 1.0.0
- flutter_plugin_android_lifecycle 2.0.5 [flutter]
- flutter_web_plugins 0.0.0 [flutter js characters collection meta typed_data vector_math]
- frontend_server_client 2.1.2 [async path]
- glob 2.0.2 [async collection file path string_scanner]
- graphs 2.1.0 [collection]
- http 0.13.4 [async http_parser meta path]
- http_multi_server 3.0.1 [async]
- http_parser 4.0.0 [charcode collection source_span string_scanner typed_data]
- image 3.1.0 [archive metaxml]
- image_picker_platform_interface 2.4.1 [flutter http meta plugin_platform_interface cross_file]
- io 1.0.3 [meta path string_scanner]
- js 0.6.3
- logging 1.0.2
- matcher 0.12.11 [stack_trace]
- meta 1.7.0
- mime 1.0.1
- nested 1.0.0 [flutter]
- package_config 2.0.2 [path]
- path 1.8.0
- path_parsing 1.0.0 [vector_math meta]
- path_provider_android 2.0.11 [flutter path_provider_platform_interface]
- path_provider_ios 2.0.7 [flutter path_provider_platform_interface]
- path_provider_linux 2.1.4 [ffi flutter meta path path_provider_platform_interface xdg_directories]
- path_provider_macos 2.0.4 [flutter meta path_provider_platform_interface]
- path_provider_platform_interface 2.0.1 [flutter meta platform plugin_platform_interface]
- path_provider_windows 2.0.4 [ffi flutter meta path path_provider_platform_interface win32]
- permission_handler_platform_interface 3.7.0 [flutter meta plugin_platform_interface]
- petitparser 4.4.0 [meta]
- platform 3.1.0
- plugin_platform_interface 2.0.2 [meta]
- pool 1.5.0 [async stack_trace]
- process 4.2.4 [file path platform]
- provider 6.0.2 [collection flutter nested]
- pub_semver 2.1.0 [collection meta]
- pubspec_parse 1.2.0 [checked_yaml collection json_annotation pub_semver yaml]
- qr 3.0.0 [meta]
- shared_preferences_android 2.0.9 [flutter meta shared_preferences_platform_interface]
- shared_preferences_ios 2.0.8 [flutter meta shared_preferences_platform_interface]
- shared_preferences_linux 2.0.3 [file flutter meta path path_provider_linux shared_preferences_platform_interface]
- shared_preferences_macos 2.0.2 [flutter shared_preferences_platform_interface]
- shared_preferences_platform_interface 2.0.0 [flutter]
- shared_preferences_web 2.0.2 [flutter flutter_web_plugins meta shared_preferences_platform_interface]
- shared_preferences_windows 2.0.3 [file flutter meta path path_provider_platform_interface path_provider_windows shared_preferences_platform_interface]
- shelf 1.2.0 [async collection http_parser path stack_trace stream_channel]
- shelf_web_socket 1.0.1 [shelf stream_channel web_socket_channel]
- sky_engine 0.0.99
- source_gen 1.2.1 [analyzer async build dart_style glob meta path source_span yaml]
- source_helper 1.3.1 [analyzer collection source_gen]
- source_span 1.8.1 [collection path term_glyph]
- stack_trace 1.10.0 [path]
- stream_channel 2.1.0 [async]
- stream_transform 2.0.0
- string_scanner 1.1.0 [charcode source_span]
- synchronized 3.0.0
- term_glyph 1.2.0
- test_api 0.4.3 [async boolean_selector collection meta source_span stack_trace stream_channel string_scanner term_glyph matcher]
- timing 1.0.0 [json_annotation]
- typed_data 1.3.0 [collection]
- universal_platform 1.0.0+1
- url_launcher_android 6.0.13 [flutter meta url_launcher_platform_interface]
- url_launcher_ios 6.0.13 [flutter meta url_launcher_platform_interface]
- url_launcher_linux 2.0.2 [flutter]
- url_launcher_macos 2.0.2 [flutter]
- url_launcher_platform_interface 2.0.4 [flutter plugin_platform_interface]
- url_launcher_web 2.0.5 [flutter flutter_web_plugins meta url_launcher_platform_interface]
- url_launcher_windows 2.0.2 [flutter]
- vector_math 2.1.1
- watcher 1.0.1 [async path]
- web_socket_channel 2.1.0 [async crypto stream_channel]
- win32 2.3.3 [ffi]
- xdg_directories 0.2.0 [meta path process]
- xml 5.3.1 [collection meta petitparser]
- yaml 3.1.0 [collection source_span string_scanner]
```

---

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Flutter on IOS: fatal error: module 'cloud\_firestore' not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64362285/flutter-on-ios-fatal-error-module-cloud-firestore-not-found)

Comment: Unfortunately no, my Podfile is not empty