# Module cloud_firestore not found

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter

When I try to build my flutter app as archive via xcode, the build fails because `Module 'cloud_firestore' not found` in file `GeneratedPluginRegistrant.m`.

If I create an archive on terminal via `flutter build ipa`, I dont receive this error.

I receive the same error when I try to build the app via Xcode. In Android Studio, everything works fine.

My podfile:

```
# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
# platform :ios, '11.0'

# CocoaPods analytics sends network stats synchronously affecting flutter build latency.
ENV['COCOAPODS_DISABLE_STATS'] = 'true'

project 'Runner', {
  'Debug' => :debug,
  'Profile' => :release,
  'Release' => :release,
}

def flutter_root
  generated_xcode_build_settings_path = File.expand_path(File.join('..', 'Flutter', 'Generated.xcconfig'), __FILE__)
  unless File.exist?(generated_xcode_build_settings_path)
    raise "#{generated_xcode_build_settings_path} must exist. If you're running pod install manually, make sure flutter pub get is executed first"
  end

  File.foreach(generated_xcode_build_settings_path) do |line|
    matches = line.match(/FLUTTER_ROOT\=(.*)/)
    return matches[1].strip if matches
  end
  raise "FLUTTER_ROOT not found in #{generated_xcode_build_settings_path}. Try deleting Generated.xcconfig, then run flutter pub get"
end

require File.expand_path(File.join('packages', 'flutter_tools', 'bin', 'podhelper'), flutter_root)

flutter_ios_podfile_setup

target 'Runner' do
  pod 'FirebaseFirestore', :git => 'https://github.com/invertase/firestore-ios-sdk-frameworks.git', :tag => '10.0.0'
  use_frameworks!
  use_modular_headers!

  flutter_install_all_ios_pods File.dirname(File.realpath(__FILE__))
end

post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    flutter_additional_ios_build_settings(target)
  end
end
```

I already removed `Podfile`, `Podfile.lock`, ran `pod update`, `pod install`, nothing worked.

Updating deployment target as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67456371/10781526) did not work.

Comment: Shot in the dark - Have you checked that you are opening the .xcworkspace and not the .xcodeproj file?

Comment: Perfect, that was the problem. Many thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This error message can occur when you open the `.xcodeproj` instead of the `.xcworkspace` file.

The `.xcworkspace` contains not only the app project itself, but also a project generated by cocoapods to manage all the dependencies.