# flutter xcode build error Module 'cloud_firestore' not found in code magic

Tags: ios, android-studio, github, podfile, codemagic

my Podfile :
target 'Runner' do
pod 'FirebaseFirestore', :git => 'https://github.com/invertase/firestore-ios-sdk-frameworks.git', :tag => '8.15.0'
end

[image: this is my code magic page]

Comment: Have you checked this? https://stackoverflow.com/q/74496688/2641242