# How do I fix this Flutter iOS build error?

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter

I'm making a simple text-to-speech app with the flutter TTS plugin, and running it on my physical iPhone and iPad for debugging.

I tried googling it, and the github repository for flutter said that I should run flutter analyze and I did that, but it says no issues found. So I'm not sure what to do. I think it's a problem with xcode.

Here is my error:

```
Failed to build iOS app
Error output from Xcode build:
↳
    ** BUILD FAILED **


Xcode's output:
↳
    <module-includes>:1:9: note: in file included from <module-includes>:1:
    #import "Headers/flutter_tts-umbrella.h"
            ^
    /Users/ragz/Desktop/Desktop/Development/Projects/flutter/useless_app/ios/Pods/Target Support
    Files/flutter_tts/flutter_tts-umbrella.h:13:9: note: in file included from
    /Users/ragz/Desktop/Desktop/Development/Projects/flutter/useless_app/ios/Pods/Target Support
    Files/flutter_tts/flutter_tts-umbrella.h:13:
    #import "FlutterTtsPlugin.h"
            ^
    /Users/ragz/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_tts-1.0.0/ios/Classes/FlutterTtsPlugin.h:1:9: error:
    'Flutter/Flutter.h' file not found
    #import <Flutter/Flutter.h>
            ^
    <unknown>:0: error: could not build Objective-C module 'flutter_tts'
    note: Using new build system
    note: Building targets in parallel
    note: Planning build
    note: Constructing build description
    warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported
    deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.4.99. (in target 'flutter_tts' from project 'Pods')
    warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported
    deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.4.99. (in target 'Flutter' from project 'Pods')

Could not build the precompiled application for the device.

Error launching application on iPad.
```

Comment: Have you added required permissions in inpo.plist file??

Comment: what do you mean?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
- Platform in ios/podfile you can use platform :ios, '10.0'
- If you are changing platform version in podfile than you have to also change version in AppFrameworkInfo.plist.
- Also change version in Deployment Target and Deployment Info of Runner.

- If not working than you have to try with this below commands using for uninstall and install again pods and Run.

flutter clean
rm -Rf ios/Pods
rm -Rf ios/.symlinks
rm -Rf ios/Flutter/Flutter.framework
rm -Rf ios/Flutter/Flutter.podspec
rm ios/Podfile
flutter run
```

Comment: I'd be careful deleting your Podfile.... customisations can have been made... I'd add a cp ios/Podfile ios/Podfile.backup into that list of commands

Answer (score 0):

Change the version to 9.0 here and it would work fine.

[image]

Comment: It was already 9.0. It still doesn’t work.

Comment: try this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63973136/the-ios-deployment-target-iphoneos-deployment-target-is-set-to-8-0-in-flutter

Answer (score 0):

you need to change the deployment target to 9 or in my opinion 10 by changing it in the xcode runner and target , also you need to change it in the pod file , uncommenting this `#platform :ios, '8.0'` by deleting the # and change the string to 10.0.
also you need to change this
`post_install do |installer|  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target| flutter_additional_ios_build_settings(target)`
into this
`post_install do |installer| installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target| flutter_additional_ios_build_settings(target) target.build_configurations.each do |config| config.build_settings['IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET'] = '10.0' end end end`
at the the end of your pod file

Answer (score 0):

Follow the below steps:

1. Go to ios/Podfile and uncomment `platform: ios` parameter and replace with

   platform :ios, '9.0'
2. Run the below command inside the ios folder structure

   pod install
3. Run command `flutter upgrade`
4. Run command `flutter run`