# Flutter IPhone 10 Build Fail

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter

Everything was working and running on my phone, then today when I tried running it on my phone again, it gave me some errors. Not sure how to solve this one. I've had this issue multiple times and I am not sure how it gets resolved hahah

Here is the list of issues:

```
Running Xcode build...
Xcode build done.                                            9.5s
Failed to build iOS app
Error output from Xcode build:
↳
    ** BUILD FAILED **


Xcode's output:
↳
    note: Using new build system
    note: Building targets in parallel
    note: Planning build
    note: Constructing build description
    warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.4.99. (in target 'image_cropper' from project 'Pods')
    warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.4.99. (in target 'TOCropViewController' from project 'Pods')
    warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.4.99. (in target 'image_picker' from project 'Pods')
    warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.4.99. (in target 'BSImageView' from project 'Pods')
    warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.4.99. (in target 'gRPC-Core' from project 'Pods')
    warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.4.99. (in target 'TOCropViewController-TOCropViewControllerBundle' from project 'Pods')
    warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.4.99. (in target 'flutter_absolute_path' from project 'Pods')
    warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.4.99. (in target 'libwebp' from project 'Pods')
    warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.4.99. (in target 'path_provider' from project 'Pods')
    warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.4.99. (in target 'url_launcher' from project 'Pods')
    warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.4.99. (in target 'BoringSSL-GRPC' from project 'Pods')
    warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.4.99. (in target 'FMDB' from project 'Pods')
    warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.4.99. (in target 'flutter_image_compress' from project 'Pods')
    warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.4.99. (in target 'BSGridCollectionViewLayout' from project 'Pods')
    warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.4.99. (in target 'Mantle' from project 'Pods')
    warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.4.99. (in target 'gRPC-C++' from project 'Pods')
    error: No profiles for 'com.quickdash' were found: Xcode couldn't find any iOS App Development provisioning profiles matching 'com.quickdash'. Automatic signing is disabled and unable to generate a profile. To enable automatic signing, pass -allowProvisioningUpdates to xcodebuild. (in target 'Runner' from project 'Runner')
    warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.4.99. (in target 'gRPC-C++-gRPCCertificates-Cpp' from project 'Pods')
    warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.4.99. (in target 'Flutter' from project 'Pods')
    warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.4.99. (in target 'leveldb-library' from project 'Pods')
    warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.4.99. (in target 'abseil' from project 'Pods')

Could not build the precompiled application for the device.

Error launching application on iPhone.
```

Also here are some details of my current environment:

````
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 1.22.5, on macOS 11.2.3 20D91 darwin-x64, locale en-GB)
    • Flutter version 1.22.5 at .../Development/flutter_tools/flutter
    • Framework revision 7891006299 (3 months ago), 2020-12-10 11:54:40 -0800
    • Engine revision ae90085a84
    • Dart version 2.10.4

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.2)
    • Android SDK at .../Library/Android/sdk
    • Platform android-30, build-tools 30.0.2
    • ANDROID_HOME = .../Library/Android/sdk
    • Java binary at: /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b3-6915495)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 12.4)
    • Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    • Xcode 12.4, Build version 12D4e
    • CocoaPods version 1.10.0

[!] Android Studio (version 4.1)
    • Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
    ✗ Flutter plugin not installed; this adds Flutter specific functionality.
    ✗ Dart plugin not installed; this adds Dart specific functionality.
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b3-6915495)

[✓] VS Code (version 1.52.1)
    • VS Code at /Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents
    • Flutter extension version 3.18.1

[✓] Connected device (2 available)
    • iPhone (mobile)    • 00008020-001C44A92EB8003A            • ios • iOS 14.4.1
    • Iphone 12 (mobile) • E3AE708C-6371-4F30-A5EA-38C8AF8111F5 • ios • com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.iOS-14-4 (simulator)
    ! Error: iPhone is busy: Copying cache files from device. Xcode will continue when iPhone is finished. (code -10)

! Doctor found issues in 1 category.
Process finished with exit code 0```
````

Comment: did you try to run flutter clean before building it again ?

Comment: @glavigno yeah! DIdn't work :/

Comment: check this post, https://stackoverflow.com/a/65572882/12107390

Comment: I am not sure about the quick dash error, but to solve the deployment target warnings: [LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64075795/13558952)

Answer (score 1):

### Rebuild the iOS folder

**This has sadly already happend a few times to me and what helped me, was always to just delete and rebuild the iOS Folder**

Delete the iOS folder (everything in there will be deleted so make sure to keep important things which weren't there by default, e.g. you edited the Info.plist, so you might keep it)

```
rm -rf ios
```

Rebuild the flutter project (Flutter will only rebuild the iOS directory as it is the only directory missing)

```
flutter create .
```

Get the packages

```
flutter pub get
```

Open Runner project

```
open ios/Runner.xcworkspace -a xcode
```

Now sign it in Xcode and run it once there, to check if everything is

**As an alternative, this also seems to work, but I haven't tried it yet**

```
flutter pub cache repair
```

Comment: I can confirm the cache repair does indeed work and no xcode required.

Comment: cache repair did not work with me. Using Flutter 2.5.1

Answer (score 0):

Change iOS version 9 to 10 in global pod file
And then Moacos to Mac issue will be solved