# The range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.55 Error While Running Flutter App on iOS Simulator

Tags: ios, firebase, flutter, cocoapods, crashlytics

So I added Firebase Crashlytics in my app and after that I started facing the following issue.

[image]

Here is my Podfile for reference

[image]

Because of the IPHONEOS_DEVELOPMENT_TARGET error I am unable to run my app and test Crashlytics on my Simulator.

For adding Firebase Crashlytics to my App I added a Run Script in Build Phases using Xcode and in the Run Script I added the following line

```
${PODS_ROOT}/FirebaseCrashlytics/run
```

Please help me out fixing this error.

To fix this error I have tried regenerating Pods Folder, Podfile, Podfile.lock, flutter clean, editing the Podfile on my own and https://stackoverflow.com/a/64075795/14876562 using this link's solution and much more.

Request for a quick reply. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The `IPHONEOS_DEVELOPMENT_TARGET` messages are warnings. The error that's blocking the build is probably from something else.

Comment: @PaulBeusterien I think the error is from the run script that I added in build phases using Xcode as if I remove that it works perfectly fine. Any idea how I could be fixing that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed the error.

The fix for this error was adding double quotes in my Run Script that I created for Firebase Crashlytics in Xcode

From:

```
${PODS_ROOT}/FirebaseCrashlytics/run
```

To:

```
"${PODS_ROOT}/FirebaseCrashlytics/run"
```