# Error on Firebase Crashlytics installation for Flutter - IOS app

Tags: ios, firebase, flutter, google-cloud-functions, crashlytics

I am following this [instructions here](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/crashlytics/overview) to install and test Firebase Crashlytics:

Here is what needs to be done in one of the steps:

##### [iOS](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/crashlytics/overview/#b-ios)

> From Xcode, select Runner from the project navigation.
>
> Select the Build Phases tab, then click + > New Run Script Phase.
>
> Add the following to the Type a script... text box underneath the Shell property:

And I paste the following as instrcuted above into XCode:

```sh
$PODS_ROOT/FirebaseCrashlytics/upload-symbols --build-phase --validate -ai <googleAppId>
$PODS_ROOT/FirebaseCrashlytics/upload-symbols --build-phase -ai <googleAppId>
```

OBS! I change `<googleAppId>` with the real AppId I get from Firebase.

And when I start my app again, I get the following error:

```
 2021-12-23 19:16:50.044 upload-symbols[31089:256482] Unable to get file attributes for dSYM file at path "/Users/ednuser/Developer/FlutterProjects/MyProject/build/ios/Debug-iphoneos/Runner.app.dSYM/Contents/Resources/DWARF/Runner"
        2021-12-23 19:16:51.049 upload-symbols[31089:256482] Unable to get file attributes for dSYM file at path "/Users/ednuser/Developer/FlutterProjects/MyProject/build/ios/Debug-iphoneos/Runner.app.dSYM/Contents/Resources/DWARF/Runner"
        2021-12-23 19:16:52.054 upload-symbols[31089:256482] Unable to get file attributes for dSYM file at path "/Users/ednuser/Developer/FlutterProjects/MyProject/build/ios/Debug-iphoneos/Runner.app.dSYM/Contents/Resources/DWARF/Runner"
        2021-12-23 19:16:53.060 upload-symbols[31089:256482] Unable to get file attributes for dSYM file at path "/Users/ednuser/Developer/FlutterProjects/MyProject/build/ios/Debug-iphoneos/Runner.app.dSYM/Contents/Resources/DWARF/Runner"
        2021-12-23 19:16:54.061 upload-symbols[31089:256482] Unable to get file attributes for dSYM file at path "/Users/ednuser/Developer/FlutterProjects/MyProject/build/ios/Debug-iphoneos/Runner.app.dSYM/Contents/Resources/DWARF/Runner"
        2021-12-23 19:16:55.066 upload-symbols[31089:256482] Unable to get file attributes for dSYM file at path "/Users/ednuser/Developer/FlutterProjects/MyProject/build/ios/Debug-iphoneos/Runner.app.dSYM/Contents/Resources/DWARF/Runner"
        2021-12-23 19:16:56.072 upload-symbols[31089:256482] Unable to get file attributes for dSYM file at path "/Users/ednuser/Developer/FlutterProjects/MyProject/build/ios/Debug-iphoneos/Runner.app.dSYM/Contents/Resources/DWARF/Runner"
        2021-12-23 19:16:57.076 upload-symbols[31089:256482] Unable to get file attributes for dSYM file at path "/Users/ednuser/Developer/FlutterProjects/MyProject/build/ios/Debug-iphoneos/Runner.app.dSYM/Contents/Resources/DWARF/Runner"
        2021-12-23 19:16:58.080 upload-symbols[31089:256482] Unable to get file attributes for dSYM file at path "/Users/ednuser/Developer/FlutterProjects/MyProject/build/ios/Debug-iphoneos/Runner.app.dSYM/Contents/Resources/DWARF/Runner"
        2021-12-23 19:16:59.085 upload-symbols[31089:256482] Unable to get file attributes for dSYM file at path "/Users/ednuser/Developer/FlutterProjects/MyProject/build/ios/Debug-iphoneos/Runner.app.dSYM/Contents/Resources/DWARF/Runner"
        2021-12-23 19:17:00.087 upload-symbols[31089:256482] Unable to get file attributes for dSYM file at path "/Users/ednuser/Developer/FlutterProjects/MyProject/build/ios/Debug-iphoneos/Runner.app.dSYM/Contents/Resources/DWARF/Runner"
        Running upload-symbols in Build Phase mode
        Validating build environment for Crashlytics...
        warning: DEBUG_INFORMATION_FORMAT should be set to dwarf-with-dsym for all configurations. This could also be a timing issue, make sure the Fabric run script build phase is the last build phase and no other scripts have moved the dSYM from the location Xcode generated it. Unable to process Runner.app.dSYM at path /Users/ednuser/Developer/FlutterProjects/MyProject/build/ios/Debug-iphoneos/Runner.app.dSYM
        Make sure your project build settings are generating a dSYM file.
        Processing dSYMs...
        Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code
        note: Using new build system
        note: Planning
        note: Build preparation complete
        note: Building targets in parallel
        /Users/ednuser/Developer/FlutterProjects/MyProject/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 15.0.99. (in target 'leveldb-library' from project 'Pods')
    Could not build the precompiled application for the device.
    
    Error launching application on Test Iphone
```

I set minimum ios target to 14 in following locations:

- AppFramworkInfo.plist
- Targets Runner -> General -> Deployment Info
- Project Runner -> Deployment Target -> ios Deployment Target
- ios/Podfile

And I still get this message when I run my app:

```
warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 15.0.99. (in target 'leveldb-library' from project 'Pods')
        Could not build the precompiled application for the device.
        
        Error launching application on Test Iphone
```

**I use a MAC M1 BigSur.**

---

I also tried the following:

- Delete ios/Podfile.lock
- And run the following in the iOS folder:

  arch -x86_64 pod install --repo-update

And I still have the same lovely problem!

But if I remove the 2 lines that I added to the Script Phase in Xcode, everything works perfectly fine!

I am totally out of solutions. Anyone who can have better ideas?

Comment: Have you taken a look into this related [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64072195/13171940)?

Comment: how did you add the googleApiId to the script code? --> can you please update the example with how you added it? (this can be a source of error)

Answer (score 10):

Following solution worked for me to fix your issue:
Goto build setting of your project then Search for debug information format in build setting and search for "Debug information format" then set "Debug information format" to "DWARF with dSYM file"

[image: Set format to dwarf with dsym file]

and make sure Generate debug symbol in build setting is set to Yes.

Comment: you saved my day!

Answer (score 1):

I somehow fixed this error by removing the spaces in the `Product Name` of the target in the Build settings.

Answer (score 0):

Build Settings -> Debug Information format -> set all build types to DWARF with dYSM File.

For me, only profile and release builds were set to DWARF with dYSM File. So I did the same with the debug build to run my app in development mode.