# Flutter cannot build application

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter, dart

I am running Xcode 13.2.1 and flutter (2.9.0, channel stable) in vscode. I am trying to build the project on an iOS 15.2 iPhone 11 Pro Max device and am ending up with the following error. I have tried many different things like a fresh restart, flutter clean, removing and reinstalling my pods. I cannot find anything else that can explain why the build is failing and am at a loss. Any new ideas would be greatly appreciated. Also if more information is needed, I can provide that too if you leave a comment.

```
** BUILD FAILED **


Xcodes output:
↳
    ld: framework not found Flutter
    clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
    note: Using new build system
    note: Planning
    note: Build preparation complete
    note: Building targets in dependency order
    /Users/fluffydoggy/development/donkee/donkee_app/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of
    supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 15.2.99. (in target 'BoringSSL-GRPC' from project 'Pods')
    /Users/fluffydoggy/development/donkee/donkee_app/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of
    supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 15.2.99. (in target 'leveldb-library' from project 'Pods')
    /Users/fluffydoggy/development/donkee/donkee_app/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of
    supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 15.2.99. (in target 'abseil' from project 'Pods')
    /Users/fluffydoggy/development/donkee/donkee_app/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of
    supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 15.2.99. (in target 'gRPC-C++' from project 'Pods')
    /Users/fluffydoggy/development/donkee/donkee_app/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of
    supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 15.2.99. (in target 'gRPC-Core' from project 'Pods')
    /Users/fluffydoggy/development/donkee/donkee_app/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of
    supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 15.2.99. (in target 'gRPC-C++-gRPCCertificates-Cpp' from project 'Pods')

Could not build the application for the simulator.
Error launching application on iPhone 11 Pro Max.
```

This is the error as a result of flutter run -v

```
#0      throwToolExit (package:flutter_tools/src/base/common.dart:10:3)
           #1      RunCommand.runCommand (package:flutter_tools/src/commands/run.dart:674:9)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #2      FlutterCommand.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command.dart:1140:27)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #3      AppContext.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:150:19)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #4      CommandRunner.runCommand (package:args/command_runner.dart:209:13)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #5      FlutterCommandRunner.runCommand.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command_runner.dart:288:9)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #6      AppContext.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:150:19)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #7      FlutterCommandRunner.runCommand (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command_runner.dart:236:5)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #8      run.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/runner.dart:62:9)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #9      AppContext.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:150:19)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #10     main (package:flutter_tools/executable.dart:94:3)
           <asynchronous suspension>
```

Comment: Check this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63973136/the-ios-deployment-target-iphoneos-deployment-target-is-set-to-8-0-in-flutter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the issue. Xcode failed to build the application because the iOS wasn't compatible with my version of flutter. I fixed this issue by changing my channel to master

```
flutter channel master
flutter upgrade
```