# Problem building IOS app after flutter upgrade

Tags: ios, flutter, dart

Folks, please help.
I upgraded flutter and now my project doesnt build.

Here's the messega I get:

```
Launching lib/main.dart on iPhone 11 Pro Max in debug mode...
lib/main.dart:1
Xcode build done.                                           58.5s
Failed to build iOS app
Error output from Xcode build:
↳
    ** BUILD FAILED **
Xcode's output:
↳
    Writing result bundle at path:
        /var/folders/0m/j17z1hfn6h18bx6q6dyhs6g80000gp/T/flutter_tools.ScC4jr/flutter_ios_build_temp_dir9oudiu/temporary_xcresult_bundle
: Error: Member not found: 'packageRoot'.
../…/interface/local_platform.dart:46
          io.Platform.packageRoot; // ignore: deprecated_member_use
                      ^^^^^^^^^^^
    Failed to package /Users/fplopez/StudioProjects/listing_project_DEV.
    Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code
    note: Using new build system
    note: Planning
    note: Build preparation complete
    note: Building targets in dependency order
    /Users/fplopez/StudioProjects/listing_project_DEV/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 15.2.99. (in target 'MTBBarcodeScanner' from project 'Pods')
    /Users/fplopez/StudioProjects/listing_project_DEV/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 15.2.99. (in target 'FMDB' from project 'Pods')
    Result bundle written to path:
        /var/folders/0m/j17z1hfn6h18bx6q6dyhs6g80000gp/T/flutter_tools.ScC4jr/flutter_ios_build_temp_dir9oudiu/temporary_xcresult_bundle
Could not build the application for the simulator.
Error launching application on iPhone 11 Pro Max.
Exited (sigterm)
```

I really need help with this. I don't know how to fix it.

Thanks

Comment: Check here [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63973136/the-ios-deployment-target-iphoneos-deployment-target-is-set-to-8-0-in-flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63973136/the-ios-deployment-target-iphoneos-deployment-target-is-set-to-8-0-in-flutter)

Comment: I faced the same issue. I fixed it.

1) flutter channel stable
2) flutter upgrade
3) flutter pub upgrade
4) Open terminals 
5) fired command cd ios and 6) pod repo update

Comment: I will try. Thanks.

Comment: Fixed! THanks Belinda. Folowed this solution >> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63973136/the-ios-deployment-target-iphoneos-deployment-target-is-set-to-8-0-in-flutter

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar error before, my problem was that I have changed the bundle identifier for some tests and when returning to the old one I faced something like this, after many searches what has worked for me is to create a new project and take the iOS module to my project then handling it again like cloning the old info.plist and so on.

Comment: I will try. Thanks