# Could not build the application for the simulator. Error launching application on iPhone 8 Plus

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter, macos

macbookpro@MacBooks-MacBook-Pro regnum_toll_update % flutter run
Launching lib/main.dart on iPhone 8 Plus in debug mode...
Running pod install...                                             22.4s
Running Xcode build...
Xcode build done.                                           214.7s
Failed to build iOS app
Error output from Xcode build:
↳
** BUILD FAILED **

Xcode's output:
↳
/Users/macbookpro/AndroidStudioProjects/regnum_toll_update/ios/Pods/FirebaseCore/FirebaseCore/Sources/FIRFirebaseUserAgent.m:95:53: warning: 'hasSwiftRuntime' is deprecated
[-Wdeprecated-declarations]
NSString *swiftFlagValue = [GULAppEnvironmentUtil hasSwiftRuntime] ? @"true" : @"false";
^
In file included from /Users/macbookpro/AndroidStudioProjects/regnum_toll_update/ios/Pods/FirebaseCore/FirebaseCore/Sources/FIRFirebaseUserAgent.m:19:
/Users/macbookpro/AndroidStudioProjects/regnum_toll_update/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/GoogleUtilities/GULAppEnvironmentUtil.h:50:25: note: 'hasSwiftRuntime' has been explicitly marked deprecated
here
+ (BOOL)hasSwiftRuntime __deprecated;
^
In module 'Foundation' imported from /Users/macbookpro/AndroidStudioProjects/regnum_toll_update/ios/Pods/FirebaseCore/FirebaseCore/Sources/FIRFirebaseUserAgent.h:17:
In module 'CoreFoundation' imported from
/Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator14.3.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/Foundation.h:6:
In module 'Darwin' imported from
/Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator14.3.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Headers/CoreFoundati
on.h:16:
/Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator14.3.sdk/usr/include/sys/cdefs.h:196:40: note: expanded from macro
'__deprecated'
#define __deprecated    **attribute**((**deprecated**))
^
1 warning generated.
While building module 'firebase_core' imported from /Users/macbookpro/Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_database-6.0.0/ios/Classes/FLTFirebaseDatabasePlugin.m:8:
In file included from :1:
In file included from /Users/macbookpro/AndroidStudioProjects/regnum_toll_update/ios/Pods/Target Support Files/firebase_core/firebase_core-umbrella.h:13:
In file included from /Users/macbookpro/Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_core-0.7.0/ios/Classes/FLTFirebaseCorePlugin.h:11:
/Users/macbookpro/Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_core-0.7.0/ios/Classes/FLTFirebasePlugin.h:9:9: error: include of non-modular header inside framework module
'firebase_core.FLTFirebasePlugin': '/Users/macbookpro/AndroidStudioProjects/regnum_toll_update/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/FirebaseCore/FirebaseCore.h'
[-Werror,-Wnon-modular-include-in-framework-module]
#import <FirebaseCore/FirebaseCore.h>
^
1 error generated.
/Users/macbookpro/Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_database-6.0.0/ios/Classes/FLTFirebaseDatabasePlugin.m:8:9: fatal error: could not build module 'firebase_core'
#import <firebase_core/FLTFirebasePlugin.h>
~~~~~~~^
2 errors generated.
note: Using new build system
note: Building targets in parallel
note: Planning build
note: Constructing build description
warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.3.99. (in target 'Reachability' from
project 'Pods')
warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.3.99. (in target 'leveldb-library'
from project 'Pods')
warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.3.99. (in target 'gRPC-Core' from
project 'Pods')
warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.3.99. (in target 'gRPC-C++' from
project 'Pods')
warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.3.99. (in target
'gRPC-C++-gRPCCertificates-Cpp' from project 'Pods')
warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.3.99. (in target 'abseil' from
project 'Pods')
warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.3.99. (in target 'BoringSSL-GRPC'
from project 'Pods')
warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.3.99. (in target 'Flutter' from
project 'Pods')

Could not build the application for the simulator.
Error launching application on iPhone 8 Plus.

Comment: Check this SO post. Upgrade the IOS target version: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63973136/the-ios-deployment-target-iphoneos-deployment-target-is-set-to-8-0-in-flutter

Answer (score 0):

Check the error message clearly. See the last line:

> warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target
> 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported
> deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.3.99. (in target 'Flutter'
> from project 'Pods')

So basically, upgrade the iPhone deployment target which is required for Firebase integration. How to do that, please check [this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63973136/the-ios-deployment-target-iphoneos-deployment-target-is-set-to-8-0-in-flutter)